# I can't find my Minecraft folder, where can I find it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find my Minecraft folder people just say use ~/Library/Applications or whatever it is, but I copy then paste it and nothing comes up!

Comment: Is this on a windows computer?

Answer (score 4):

To get to your Minecraft folder on Windows, do the following:

1. Press Windows Key + R at the same time. This should open the `Run...` dialog box.
2. In this dialog box, enter `%appdata%/.minecraft`
3. Press `OK`

---

To get to your Minecraft folder on Mac OS X, do the following:

1. Open Finder
2. Press Command + Shift + G at the same time.  This should open a dialog box with `Go to the folder...` as title.
3. In the dialog box, enter `~/Library/Application Support/Minecraft`
4. Press `Go`. You should now be in your Minecraft folder.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X:
Click on 'go' in Finder, and while holding the alt key, click on library, then Application Support, then minecraft.

Answer (score -3):

Click on the center bar at the top and type "%appdata%" (without quotes) then the minecraft folder will be there.